# How to implement a PATCH request for an object with 10+ fields with specific validation

Tags: rest, validation, go, mux

*I am using gorm v1 and gorilla/mux (REST API)*

let's say I have

```
type User struct{

  A string

  B int

  C int

  .

  .

  Z string

}
```

Fields from A-H are mandatory and have a few other validations on them like

> min/max size

> no spaces

> etc

Now, If I have a request
**PATCH**: `api/v1/user/1`

**Body**: `{C:10}`

How do I figure out if `C` was given as body in my API endpoint so that I can **validate** `C` (or any given field)
should I be doing this with a lot of if's and switch cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via [go-playground/validator](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10).
If you don't wanna use external library, then you'll have to use reflect package, that's what essentially the validator package does as well.